# "Unsubscribe" From CKQuerySubscription Without Removing It (Multiple Users)

Tags: swift, swift3, cloudkit

I have a Role Type that *multiple* users are subscribed to `recordCreation` changes for.

It's easy to add new users to this `CKQuerySubscription` by using its `subscriptionID`, however the issue arises when I try to 'unsubscribe' one of the users from the subscription using the `CKContainer.default().publicCloudDatabase.delete(withSubscriptionID:)` method.

Rather than just stopping this device from receiving any further notifications, it deletes the subscription (for all other users as well).

So my question is: how do I remove one user from a `CKQuerySubscription` without deleting the subscription for other users who are also subscribed to it?

Comment: I'm curious, how did you manage to add users to an existing subscription?

Comment: I simply specify the subscription's ID using the following constructor:

let updatesSubscription = CKQuerySubscription(recordType: "Update", predicate: NSPredicate(value: true), subscriptionID: "63453537-75E8-4A53-82A1-75757F99E1CB", options: .firesOnRecordCreation)

This then 'adds' this user to the existing subscription.

Is this bad practise?

Comment: I would have expected that to create separate subs for each user with that ID. You may have exposed, though, a potential for conflicts in my own app. My intent was for each user to have their own sub for each record of interest. They can unsubscribe by deleting their own sub. I had to deconflict the sub id so each sub had a unique id for each record type. But I never considered the ID conflicting between users. I need to check that. :)

Comment: Ah okay, that's a good idea... but I can't submit multiple subscriptions that are the same even if from different users. I get an error referring to "duplicate subscription"...  do you not have that problem when you have each user 'own' their own subscription (rather than share one)?

Comment: I only see the "duplicate" error when I use the same predicate multiple times for 1 user. I haven't seen it when multiple users create the same subs.

Comment: Oooooooh I've just realised this must be because I have been using the same Apple ID for debugging (in simulator and both devices). Thanks for your help, Thunk